# Retag suggestion: [mtg-duels-pc-game] -> [magic-duels]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retagging

We currently have the tag [mtg-duels-pc-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-pc-game) to refer to the video game Magic Duels. This tag name is not accurate, because the title of the game is "Magic Duels", not "Magic: the Gathering Duels" or "MTG Duels" or similar. In addition, as [this question](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/33995/shadows-over-innistrad-starter-box) shows, it is not exclusively a PC game. I recommend that we change this to [magic-duels](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels). That will match the name of the game, and it will not conflict with any other existing product that we support, as far as I know.

Any issues, concerns, etc?

Comment: That sounds logical, especially since duels is available on mobile devices as well.

Answer (score 3):

I created the [mtg-duels-pc-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mtg-duels-pc-game) tag a while back.

I added on the "pc-game" bit because of a related issue I've observed on another site. On RPG.SE, we have a [[dnd-encounters]](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dnd-encounters) tag. D&D is a popular game, and it prominently features fights we call "encounters", and sometimes a person asking about encounters in D&D will use the [dnd-encounters] tag. However, the [dnd-encounters] tag is [actually for a specific official organised play program called "D&D Encounters"](http://dndadventurersleague.org/get-involved/dd-encounters/), so we retag these questions to use another tag like [encounter-design].

I added "pc-game" to head off this kind of situation from the outset. MTG is, after all, regularly played using duels.

That said, calling it "mtg duels" when it's called "magic duels" is definitely wrong. (At the time I thought it was called "Magic: the Gathering — Duels" or something.)

---

I'd agree with [magic-duels](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels) now though. That sounds OK. We might have to do some retagging but probably not very much.

If we find ourselves doing a lot of retagging, we may want to rename it to [magic-duels-video-game](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magic-duels-video-game).